# enforcing version integrity on git repos

Tags: ransomware, git

I'm working through a tabletop on code control and the question of ransomware came up. I figure someone has solved this.

Git is naturally resistant to ransomware - if someone's local copy of code gets encrypted and committed, version control allows their change to be discarded.

Advanced malware teams often go after the backups, though - the APT team that hit Garmin sat around for 8 months to make sure the backups were wiped before springing the lockout notification.

I haven't run across many examples of ransomware crews going after source code, but it seems like a reasonable target - losing source code for your main software product would be a big hit.

It looks like the default contribute role in github and bitbucket allows deletion of previous commits. I see the need for it - if a commit has embedded secrets, you may have to sanitize them out of the history. This should be rare, though. Is it possible to restrict commit deletion to only a privileged account? Can you set up alerting on your git platform for these actions? I can imagine IoCs at different severities for "tried a commit deletion and failed," "did a commit deletion with a prived account," and maybe some correlation rules on volume. Does anyone have a config recipe that solves these problems and the next ones on this topic I haven't thought of yet?

Comment: I would simply backup the repo regularly.

Comment: Frequent backups are the old-school way of addressing ransomware, but I've noticed the approach has been losing ground in favor of version-controlled buckets or distributed processing+serverless storage. Git is 90% of the way to that model, why move backwards to a harder-to-manage and less-granular control?

Comment: Ransomware isn't that old, so I think you are over-stating how antiquated backups are as a mitigation. Note that any move to "distributed processing+serverless storage" will be met by changes to the attack model to include them. Immutable or offline backups continue to be best practice and future-proof.